# как исправить данную ошибку fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift3

Прикрепляю скриншот, впервые столкнулся с такой ошибкой, не могу исправить.Если есть профессионалы или умельцы.Подскажите что он хочет и как исправить.Буду очень благодарен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш selectedEvent.match возвращает nil, и судя по всему так и есть - вы ему нигде ничего не присвоили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть переменная `selectedEvent`, которая объявлена как Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Type (посредством добавления '!' в конце объявления)

```
var selectedEvent : Event!
```

Что это значит? что когда программа будет пытаться читать значение из этой переменной, она должна крэшнуться если там nil

> The Swift language defines the postfix ! as syntactic sugar for the named type Optional, which is defined in the Swift standard library, with the additional behavior that it’s automatically unwrapped when it’s accessed. If you try to use an implicitly unwrapped optional that has a value of nil, you’ll get a runtime error.

Что происходит у вас? именно то, что написано в документации. Другими словами, это правильное поведение программы.

Как это исправить?

1) присвоить что то в переменную до того, как из нее читать.

либо

2) не объявлять ее как implicitly unwrapped (убрать '!', или заменить на '?')

Comment: Спасибо .За подсказку .Я уже додумался и вспомнил в чем проблема.Уже пробую  но уже в другой строке требует.